# replace document in IE modal dialog

Tags: html

Browser : IE6/IE7.

I want to load a new document into my html modal dialog, either via a form target or a javascript function.

```
<html> <!-- quirks mode -->
<head>
<script>
function openModal(url) {
    if(window.showModalDialog)  showModalDialog(url);
    else {
        try {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
            open(url, "", "modal=yes");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("dialog windows unsupported by browser");
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background:red" onload="setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor='white'},100)">
<a href="javascript:openModal(location.href)">Open Modal</a>
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Send Form" />
</form>
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Reload content</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In Gecko-based browsers, it works.

In IE, when in the modal dialog window, the form opens a new window (even if I specify the `target="_self"` attribute), and the javascript reload() fails silently. If I try to do a `location.replace(location.href)` or `location.href=_someurl_`, it opens a new window.

So my question : how can I get IE to replace the current document in a modal dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that handles the `<form>` part of the problem : add

```
<base target="_self" />
```

in the `<head>` section of the page.

It doesn't resolve the javascript issue, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.name = "SomeWindowName";
window.open("www.microsoft.com", "SomeWindowName");
```

...works. this must be used within the dialog window instead of `location.replace`

Comment: Surprisingly, it actually does. You just need to replace `document.location = [url]` with those two lines. It even works for refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.name="SomeWindowName";
window.open("www.microsoft.com","SomeWindowName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same problem with Internet Explorer 8, so after playing around with it for a while it seems that there are some solutions such as

```
location.reload();return false;
```

or

```
window.location = window.location;
```

or

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

However, none of them work for me - either nothing happens, or, best case, a new window opens.

What I've come up with as some kind of workaround is to use

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

It may not work for all constellations as you need a form on your page (and make sure that the form submission does not perform any unwanted changes), but it worked for me. Also make sure that you don't forget to put the

```
<base target="_self" />
```

into the header of your page as described by Alsciende.

HTH

G.